# How to normalize a table that contains a CK not included in the PK?

Tags: database-design, normalization

I have the following table. The PK is **model_ID**.
Assuming that the **modelName** field is unique(that is, no two brands can have an identical **modelName**), there is a transitive dependency between **modelName** and **brand**.

What is the optimal solution for the table to comply with 3NF, without having the **modelName** field as part of the PK?

[image: table]

Comment: @MikePartridge - A database developer would would be equally qualified. I typically don't go to the dba site because I'm rarely involved with backups, disk drives, files structures, security settings, installation, etc.

Comment: I question your assumption that modelName is unique.  They can change and are outside your control.  Why not just stick with a primary key?

Comment: @JeffO The dba.se site is not only about database administration (despite it's name - that was a poor choice and has been discussed endlessly in meta). I have no idea if the question is on topic here but it's certainly on topic in dba as well. I say one of the 2 Qs should be closed (by the OP or mods.)

Comment: Why don't you want to make model name a part of pk if it represents a natural identity anyway?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer the question about transitive dependency:

If `modelName` is unique then it is a candidate key, so **there is no transitive dependency.** The table is at least in 3NF.

Answer (score 1):

Model name does not need to be part of the PK.  The problem with this table is brand. "Scott" is repeated. Model relies on Brand, but brand does not rely on model.

Create a brand table. Turn the Model.brand to Brand_FK.